# What is the usage difference between adjective and of + noun

Tags: adjectives

What is the usage difference between adjective and of + noun? When is more suitable or precise to use "of +noun"?

For example what is the difference between:

> Music is of necessity for human life.

and:

> Music is necessary for human life.

Other similar examples:

> important VS of importance.
>
> beautiful VS of beauty

Comment: *A thing **of beauty**, A matter **of necessity**, An issue **of importance*** are all valid collocations, but they're very uncommon "stylised" forms compared to *A **beautiful** thing, A **necessary** matter, An **important** issue*. As a general principle, non-native speakers should avoid those stylised versions, because there are few contexts where they work well (almost *none* where they're *necessary*), and many contexts where they simply don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is not idiomatic; I suspect it is not even grammatical.

> Music is necessary for human lefe

means exactly the same as

> Music is a necessity for human life.

They are just different ways to express the same thought.

I suspect that you are thinking of the phrase

> Of necessity, a [logical] consequence is X

which means the same thing as

> Logically, a necessary consequence is X.

That phrase “of necessity” is always (almost always?) tied to a formal train of logical deduction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do not undertand what do you mean by " a formal train of logical deduction".  I know my exmaples have the same meaning. My main confusion is that what the usage difference between adjective and of + noun is?

Comment: Your first sentence should read _a necessity_.  The phrase _of necessity_ is not used in this context (saying that something is needed). See [this definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-necessity)